# Solving the system $(P1 - P2)\cdot y+S\cdot x-P2\cdot S=0$ and $y\cdot\cos(\alpha)+x\cdot\sin(\alpha)-H=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am trying to validate some calculations of a paper I'm reading for a high school math project. In the paper, the authors have two line equations:

\begin{align*}
(P1 - P2) \cdot y + S \cdot x - P2 \cdot S &= 0 \\
y \cdot \cos(\alpha) + x \cdot \sin(\alpha) - H &= 0
\end{align*}

where $P1, P2, S, H$ are just some constants. The authors then state that when solved simultaneously, the coordinates of when the two lines intersect are

\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{\frac{H(P1-P2)}{\cos(\alpha)} + SP2}{S + \tan(\alpha)(P1-P2)} \\
y &= \frac{S(\frac{H}{\sin(\alpha)} - P2)}{S\cot(\alpha) + (P1-P2)}
\end{align*}

There were no derivations shown (this seems like normal practice from the papers I have read so far, so no complaints), so I am trying to fill in the gaps between the given line equations and the intersect coordinates. This is what I have so far

\begin{align*}
(P1 - P2) \cdot y + S \cdot x - P2 \cdot S = 0 
&\rightarrow y = -\frac{S \cdot x}{P1 - P2} + \frac{P2 \cdot S}{P1 - P2}
\\
y \cdot \cos(\alpha) + x \cdot \sin(\alpha) - H = 0
&\rightarrow y = -x\tan(\alpha) + \frac{H}{\cos(\alpha)}
\end{align*}

Thus, by setting these equations equal to each other, one gets

\begin{align*}
-\frac{S \cdot x}{P1 - P2} + \frac{P2 \cdot S}{P1 - P2} &=
-x\tan(\alpha) + \frac{H}{\cos(\alpha)}
\\
-\frac{S \cdot x}{P1 - P2} + x\tan(\alpha) &=
-\frac{P2 \cdot S}{P1 - P2} + \frac{H}{\cos(\alpha)}
\\
x \cdot \left(\tan(\alpha) - \frac{S}{P1 - P2}\right) &=
\frac{H}{\cos(\alpha)} -\frac{P2 \cdot S}{P1 - P2}
\\
x &=
\frac{\frac{H}{\cos(\alpha)} -\frac{P2 \cdot S}{P1 - P2}}{\tan(\alpha) - \frac{S}{P1 - P2}} \cdot \frac{(P1-P2)}{(P1-P2)}
\\
x &= \frac{\frac{H(P1-P2)}{\cos(\alpha)} - SP2}{\tan(\alpha)(P1-P2) - S}
\end{align*}

My plan was to first solve for $x$ and then use that to solve for $y$, but it seems like my approach is incorrect since my result doesn't match with that of the paper. I have checked the math and have not noticed what I did wrong. Any help to point out what I did wrong or ways to approach the problem differently is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: Origin of problem
[image]

[image]

Comment: The algebra is easier if you abstract the system to, say, $ax+by+c=0$ and $dx+ey+f=0$. Solve *that* in whatever way you like, then substitute $a\to S$, $b\to (P_1-P_2)$, etc.

Comment: My calculations indicate some typo either in the problem or in the solution - Can you post a screenshot of your maths project problem?

Comment: @Dr.Sundar So, the project is supposed to show us students the importance of algebra in higher learning environments. To do that, the teacher picks random papers that have calculation steps omitted and asks the students to fill in the derivation.

Comment: @Dr.Sundar I have added the part of the paper that has the equations.

Comment: Your result for $x$ is exact

Answer (score 1):

The given equations are:

$ S x + (P_1 - P_2) y = P_2 S $                **(1)**

$ \sin \alpha \ x + \cos \alpha \ y = H$

or

$ x + \cot \alpha y = {H \over \sin \alpha}$

or

$ S x + S \cot \alpha \  y = {S H \over \sin \alpha}$ **(2)**

(2) - (1) gives

$ [ S \cot \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) ] y = {S H \over \sin \alpha} - P_2 S $

or

$ y = { {S H \over \sin \alpha} - P_2 S \over
      S \cot \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) } $

which can be simplified further as

$ y = { S (H - P_2 \sin \alpha ) \over
 S \cos \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) \sin \alpha} $.

Substituting this into (1), we get

$
S x + {(P_1 - P_2) S (H - P_2 \sin \alpha) \over
  S \cos \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) \sin \alpha} = P_2 S
$

Dividing by $S$, we get
$
  x + {(P_1 - P_2)  (H - P_2 \sin \alpha) \over
  S \cos \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) \sin \alpha} = P_2  
$

Thus, we get
$
x = P_2 - {(P_1 - P_2)  (H - P_2 \sin \alpha) \over
  S \cos \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) \sin \alpha} $

After simplification, we get

$
x = {P_2 S \cos \alpha - (P_1 - P_2) H \over
   S \cos \alpha + (P_2 - P_1) \sin \alpha} $

Comment: I think you may have accidentally switched P1 - P2 to P2 - P1 without carrying a negative sign out front when you do (2) - (1)

Comment: I corrected my solution - This is mathematically correct! I feel that there may be some typo in the printed answer you posted in your question!

Comment: Kindly check my corrected answer. If it is satisfactory, kindly upvote and accept it. Thanks.